# SQL return sum of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
TYPE  VALUE
A       4
A       5
A       6
B       1
B       1
```

I need to check which type has ***sum(value) < 3***, but i can't find a way to return sum(value) of a specific type for the comparison operator.

Answer (score 3):

Just group by the type and apply a `having` clause:

```
SELECT   type
FROM     mytbale
GROUP BY type
HAVING   SUM(value) < 3
```